# Построит датафрэйм из имени файла

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\77081\Desktop\Новая папка' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.s2p")
new_list = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', skiprows= 3, header=None)
    new_list.append(df)
dataset = pd.concat(new_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
dataset.columns = ['freq', 'MS11', 'IS11', 'MS21', 'IS21','MS12', 'IS12','MS22', 'IS22']
dataset.shape
#Out:(8640, 9)
```

Я должен добавить столбец существующему датафрэйм. У меня в общем 48 фалов, у каждого 180 строк(180*48=8640). И я должен добавить столбец где каждой строке соответствует имя файла.

Comment: Имя файла у вас в  `filename`  . Перед тем как делать  `append`  добавьте в датафрэйм столбец с именем файла.

Comment: А как это сделать? то есть как добавить?

Comment: Просто если сделать как вы сказали то в результате все 8640 строк будут соответствовать одного имя файла а мне нужно чтобы каждая строка соответствовало своему имени.

Comment: Перед  `new_list.append(df)`  в цикле сделайте  `df['filename'] = filename`  и  `dataset.columns`  подправьте.

Comment: filname это имя только одного файла, и когда я делаю как вы предлагали то имя первого файла будет во всех строк. А у меня 48 имен файла и я должен сделать так чтобы для каждого файла соответствовало  по 180 строк. То есть свои данные.

Comment: вы попробовали сделать, то что я предлагал? какой результат?

Comment: У меня есть 48 файлов. когда я сделал как вы написали то название первого файла перешло во все строки. Я хочу добавить столбец с именем файла в каждую строку, чтобы потом отследить, откуда он взялся.

Comment: добавьте в свой вопрос код который вы пробовали запускать и полученный результат

Comment: Извините оказывается сработало, но имя фала 'Cu_15_C5-1_4,6_multibias_spar_-1.000_6.000'. Что я должен сделать что бы в таблице осталось только -1.000_6.000.

Comment: Возможно достаточно будет одного среза или сделать  `split` , а может потребуется составлять регулярное выражение. Лучше оформите это отдельным вопросом, опишите свою проблему и приведите минимальный набор данных.